# Quotation mark incorrect when using crosstab() in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pivot, quotes, crosstab

I have a table `t1` as below:

```
create table t1 (
  person_id int,
  item_name varchar(30),
  item_value varchar(100)
);
```

There are five records in this table:

```
person_id | item_name | item_value
   1        'NAME'      'john'
   1        'GENDER'    'M'
   1        'DOB'       '1970/02/01'
   1        'M_PHONE'   '1234567890'
   1        'ADDRESS'   'Some Addresses unknown'
```

Now I want to use crosstab function to extract `NAME`, `GENDER` data, so I write a SQL as:

```
select * from crosstab(
  'select person_id, item_name, item_value from t1 
   where person_id=1 and item_name in ('NAME', 'GENDER') ') 
as virtual_table (person_id int, NAME varchar, GENDER varchar)
```

My problem is, as you see the SQL in `crosstab()` contains condition of `item_name`, which will cause the quotation marks to be incorrect.
How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 28):

To avoid any confusion about how to escape single quotes and generally simplify the syntax, use [**dollar-quoting**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) for the query string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   $$
   SELECT person_id, item_name, item_value
   FROM   t1 
   WHERE  person_id = 1
   AND    item_name IN ('NAME', 'GENDER')
   $$
   ) AS virtual_table (person_id int, name varchar, gender varchar);
```

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

And you should add `ORDER BY` to your query string. I quote [the manual for the `tablefunc` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#AEN161436):

> In practice the SQL query should always specify `ORDER BY 1,2` to ensure
> that the input rows are properly ordered, that is, values with the
> same row_name are brought together and correctly ordered within the
> row. Notice that crosstab itself does not pay any attention to the
> second column of the query result; it's just there to be ordered by,
> to control the order in which the third-column values appear across the page.

See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Answer (score 4):

Double your single quotes to escape them:

```
select * from crosstab(
  'select person_id, item_name, item_value from t1 
   where person_id=1 and item_name in (''NAME'', ''GENDER'') ') 
as virtual_table (person_id int, NAME varchar, GENDER varchar)
```